# limit of files modified by a user for a period of time

Tags: linux, windows, script

Is it possible to do this on windows and linux?

Example: user robert can only modify 100 files in 15 minutes, exceeding 100 files in a period of 15 minutes prevents him from modifying more files until the administrator manually removes the lock.

Comment: Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here.

Comment: Sure write a program. You can use WMI https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-can-i-monitor-for-different-types-of-events-with-just-one-script/